# How to set Solaris SPARC to run in little endian mode?

Tags: sparc, endianness, solaris-10

Is there a way to set Solaris running on SPARC to run on little endian mode?

I've been reading that the v9 architecture chip is a bi-endian chip, though by default, the system runs in big endian. How to switch it to little endian?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No the Little endian mode is pretty much just for making bus accesses easier. Since many newer sun machines have PCI which is little endian it made loads of sense to add support for a little endian mode. However I doubt you would use it much if ever in user code.

Using the bi-endian feature is pretty much kernel/driver specific.